# jQuery only working sporadically or on a page refresh/hard reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery to read the URL of the page to determine which page the user is on and then change the background accordingly. My code works great, sometimes... I've tried using $(window).load(function() to no avail and the only answer I can find here is to use $( document ).ready(function() but that's not much help because that's how I wrote the code to begin with, and it's not working as it should. I also attempted to force the page to reload inside the function but that was pointless as well, ( I didn't have much hope for it anyway). When it doesn't work a simple click of the refresh button will get it to work. I have also tried putting the script tag in the header and footer, no difference. I have implemented the same code on different sites and in both cases, it works fine... I thought that maybe it was a caching issue but multiple hard reloads proved otherwise.

You can see for yourself at http://maisonshowroom.com/ click through the nav and the background is supposed to change for each page. I also have a console.log message that should reflect the URL, sometimes it's correct...but that just raises more questions for me, regardless if it's correct or not it should still have a background image rather than just being blank.

Here's my code

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
//changes background images based on which page user is on//

var currentPage = window.location.href;

console.log(currentPage);

if (currentPage.includes('about')) {
    $('.wrapper-inner').css('background-image', 
'url(http://maisonshowroom.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/maison-
about.jpg)');
}

else if (currentPage.includes('services'))
{
    $('.wrapper-inner').css('background-image', 'url(http://maisonshowroom.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/maison-service-e1506643269331.jpg)');
}

else if (currentPage.includes('products'))
{
    $('.wrapper-inner').css('background-image', 'url(http://maisonshowroom.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/maison-product.jpg)');
}

else if (currentPage.includes('contact'))
{
    $('.wrapper-inner').css('background-image', 'url(http://maisonshowroom.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/maison-contact.jpg)');
}

else {
    $('.wrapper-inner').css('background-image', 'url(http://maisonshowroom.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/maison-about.jpg)');
}
```

});

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you doing this? Wouldn't it be easier to set these in CSS files for each page? Or give `.wrapper-inner` a specific parent for each page, and use a single CSS file.

Comment: Also, for `services`, your condition is looking to see if the URL string passed includes the sub-string `services`, which it doesn't. It has the string `service`, but not `services`. That extra `s` will make the condition equate to false.

Comment: Same issue with `products`, drop the `s`, make it singular like in the URL you passed.

Comment: You realize parts of your site are loaded via AJAX (about, gallery, contact, etc), and that means no real page navigation. Therefore your `$(document).ready()` callback isn't going to be called again for those "pages"

Comment: No I did not realize this, I wasn't aware that AJAX would get in the way, nor am I familiar with AJAX so this doesn't do much for me. Why does it work on refreshes then?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All I needed to do was disable the AJAX page transition from the WordPress dashboard. Thanks, Patrick Evans, for pointing out that it was being handled by AJAX, I would have never guessed.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
window.location.reload();
```

and fix this line :

```
'url(http://maisonshowroom.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/maison-
about.jpg)');
```

to:

```
  $('.wrapper-inner').css('background-image', 
'url(http://maisonshowroom.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/maison-about.jpg)');
```

One single line

Comment: Does this actually affect the outcome though? I'd say it is definitely an unnecessary step, but having it won't keep OP from getting the URL they need.

Comment: line 12 and 13 of his code is the problem , i edit my answer

Comment: Note that more than likely is just an issue from editing the question, the actual script on their site does not contain the newline in the middle of the string.

Comment: Sorry window.location.reload(); isn't actually in the code. I must have copied a solution I was playing with.